# Azure AD authentication, 404 not found on /signin-oidc

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

The past few days, I have gotten a 404 error on /signin-oidc after successfully authenticated with Azure AD against my ASP.NET Core web app using the Microsoft Edge browser. This worked until recently and it still works fine in Firefox from the same PC and from Safari on mobile devices (iPhone / iPad).

This seems to be exact the same issue as described (a bit better) here: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/539

So, the issue is related to running the ASP.NET application behind a Nginx ingress controller somehow. Still strange that it works in Firefox and Safari, but not in Edge and Chrome.

How can one troubleshoot this?

Comment: Hi..do you mean that you get 404 only on edge while getting redirected from Azure ad and the application successfully authenticates on Chrome and Firefox ?

Comment: @AdityaSingh Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Hello @OlavT Are you still experiencing this issue ?

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity Yes, the same issue is still present.

Comment: Testing it today I got the following behavior in Edge. After successfully authenticating with Azure AD, I see the browser looping a few times and then I get "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again.". Firefox works with no issues.

Comment: @OlavT Sorry for the delayed response. Just wanted to confirm, have you already tried clearing cookies/cache on Edge and InPrivate window?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both clearing cookies and running InPrivate. Exactly same behavior. If you want to see you can reach out to me internally in MSFT (olavt@).

Comment: I have updated the description with new information (about running in AKS with Nginx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for ASP.NET Core to work correctly with proxy servers and load balancers some configuration is required as described in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-6.0

This has been simplified in .net 6 and I fixed this problem today by upgrading my web application to .net 6 and setting the environment variable ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED to true when running it in a Kubernetes environment. I tested by running it in Azure Container Apps (which is built on top of Kubernetes).

Comment: In .Net 6, do you still need to configure the ForwardedHeadersOptions ? or just set the ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED = true is enough ? Thank you

Comment: @HoangMinh According to my testing you only need to set the ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED environment variable to true.