# Redirect URL changes from https to http after users authenticated with azure active directory in azure aks

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-aks, asp.net-core-6.0

I've been struggling to find a solution for this issue. Basically I have web application that allows users to sign in with their azure active directory using OpenIdConnect. Everything works perfectly fine on my local. However, when deployed to azure aks, somehow the redirect url changes from https to http when user is authenticated. This causes an exception in azure ad:

AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'http://example.abc.com/signin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'c853f6fe-5f4a-436e-b329-ff6da9ab89ab'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this.

I defined the redirect URI in the application as https://example.abc.com/signin-oidc and no wonder that it does not match. However, I'm struggling to find out why it's happening and how I can resolve it. I'm using .NET 6 and AKS client version 1.22.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the solution for myself. Thanks to the answer in other [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431431/azure-ad-authentication-404-not-found-on-signin-oidc/72061806?noredirect=1#comment129952490_72061806)

Since I'm using .NET 6, all I have to do is

1. Set the ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED = true AND
2. Add these two lines suggested from @Venkatesan to my ingress yml

   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

Everything works perfectly after that.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: In our case (Blazor Server) we had to indeed set the environment variable ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED to true in the docker file.

`ENV ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED true`

The other 2 settings I cannot confirm; possibly they were true by default or just did not apply in our case?

Answer (score 1):

> AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'http://example.abc.com/signin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'c853f6fe-5f4a-436e-b329-ff6da9ab89ab'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this.

The above error occurs usually when redirect Url in the authentication are not configured in Azure AD like.

- Accessing ***Website*** from a different address than what you have defined for your application causes an error.
- please check if you have made a mistake in the configuration itself.

[image]

***From your case :***

- Please make sure you set ssl redirects url to **True**

**Note:**
By default  controller redirects HTTP clients to 443 port -https  ,if it has TLS is enabled

- In ingress routing yaml file if it is set to **`false`**, try to set it or modify it to **`true`**

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

- Also as you said you are using  `.net make sure you have set headers to true.`

Please check that header size in 32k in annotations.

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "32k"`

***Reference:***
[Error AADSTS50011 - The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application . - Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50011-reply-url-mismatch?source=recommendations)